# Quiz - adding and removing nodes

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to remove the **current question value** below and add in the next question, when button is clicked. Made a poor attempt and could do with some help. Heres the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/9675fvu2/9/)

```
var allQuestions = [
{
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 4 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "8", "18", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 5 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "9", "10", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
}];

 var button = document.getElementById('next');
 var question = document.getElementById("question");

button.onclick = function(){
  for(var i=0; i<allQuestions.length;i++){
    question.innerHTML = allQuestions[i].question;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. Check it out.

Code below shows in order

http://jsfiddle.net/seshakiran/9675fvu2/17/

```
var allQuestions = [
{
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 4 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "8", "18", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 5 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "9", "10", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
}];

var button = document.getElementById('next');
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var cnt=0;
button.onclick = function(){

  question.innerHTML = allQuestions[cnt].question;
cnt+=1;

}
```

Code below shows random order

http://jsfiddle.net/seshakiran/9675fvu2/11/  -- Random

```
 var allQuestions = [
{
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 4 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "8", "18", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
},{
    question: "What is 5 + 4?", 
    choices: ["24", "9", "10", "16"], 
    correctAnswer:0
}];

var button = document.getElementById('next');
var question = document.getElementById("question");
button.onclick = function(){    
for(var i=0; i<allQuestions.length;i++){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuestions.length);
  question.innerHTML = allQuestions[rnd].question;
}
}
```

The statement below is the one that randomizes the number between the length of the array items.

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuestions.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're going for, but this at least changes the questions on each click.

```
var i = 0;
button.onclick = function(){
    question.innerHTML = allQuestions[i].question;
      i++;
    if(i === 3){
      i = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just noticed the first answer was pretty much the same as this minus this answer cycles back to the first question after the last question.

Comment: Also probably shouldn't use i as the variable unless you want to wrap the whole answer in an iife to encapsulate it all into that scope.